# Design Pattern for writing file with minimum memory consumption

Tags: java, performance, design-patterns, out-of-memory, file-writing

I need to write a file by reading an xml, containing format information and values to be fetched from database. I am working on large number of records(200,000). 
I have tried keeping all the data in memory but got out of memory error.
I have tried hitting database again and again but then I got performance issue. As queries being hit again and again decreases performance.

Steps involved for the process:

1. hitting db to get all records for which file is to be created
2. reading xml file using Jaxb
3. creating map of all the data obtained from step 1.
4. iterating over map obtained from step1
5. deriving what data need to be displayed from format object created
   in step 2
6. appending result in a string for each record and then writing same
   into file

Though, finally I resolved this by reading a predefined count of data once and write file for this and then work on next bunch. But I have not followed any design pattern for this.

Is there a design pattern that uses minimum memory and let me write file efficiently?

Answer (score 2):

The design pattern is called **[Pagination](http://ui-patterns.com/patterns/Pagination)** (using a cursor). When you send a query to Oracle DB for example, the default number of results in the resultset returned is 50. Only when you ask the resultset to get `next()` it'll return the next 50 results. That's how most DBs work and designed to be efficient for such a pattern (see this [code example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html)):

```
public static void viewTable(Connection con, String dbName)
    throws SQLException {

    Statement stmt = null;
    String query =
        "select COF_NAME, SUP_ID, PRICE, " +
        "SALES, TOTAL " +
        "from " + dbName + ".COFFEES";

    try {
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        while (rs.next()) {
            String coffeeName = rs.getString("COF_NAME");
            int supplierID = rs.getInt("SUP_ID");
            float price = rs.getFloat("PRICE");
            int sales = rs.getInt("SALES");
            int total = rs.getInt("TOTAL");
            System.out.println(coffeeName + "\t" + supplierID +
                               "\t" + price + "\t" + sales +
                               "\t" + total);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e ) {
        JDBCTutorialUtilities.printSQLException(e);
    } finally {
        if (stmt != null) { stmt.close(); }
    }
}
```

So, you can open the file, and write every "page" of results that you're getting, ask for the next page etc. Once you're done - close the file.

Comment: Well. just what about modifying `Composite` or `Visitor` design patterns for this scenario?

Comment: @FarhangAmary I don't understand your comment. If you think that these design patterns are relevant to the question - please post it as an answer that explains how.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I have never read and used paging pattern in Java batch. Can you please share a link for paging design pattern, so that I can get some more insight on this pattern.

Comment: @AkhilKhandelwal sure, I also added a link to the answer: http://ui-patterns.com/patterns/Pagination

Comment: Thanks I will look into this pattern. Please note I have added steps for the java batch. Please suggest if any other design pattern is applicable for same.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you refer by "java batch". And yes, since this is a design pattern it's applicable (can be implemented) to any tool.

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing to XML, I suggest writing out each record as you read it in.  This way you only need enough memory for one record at a time and it doesn't matter how many records you have.

e.g.

```
Statement stmt = null;
String query =
    "select COF_NAME, SUP_ID, PRICE, " +
    "SALES, TOTAL " +
    "from " + dbName + ".COFFEES";

try {
    stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    while (rs.next()) {
        xmlFile.println("<coffee>\n" +
              "<coffeename>" + rs.getString("COF_NAME") + "</coffeename>\n" +
              "<supId>" + rs.getInt("SUP_ID")+ "</supId>\n" + 
              "<price>" + rs.getFloat("PRICE") + "</price>\n" + 
              "<sales>" + rs.getInt("SALES") + "</sales>\n" + 
              "<total>" + rs.getInt("TOTAL") + "</total>\n" +
              "</coffee>");
    }
} catch (SQLException e ) {
    JDBCTutorialUtilities.printSQLException(e);
} finally {
    if (stmt != null) { stmt.close(); }
}
```

You may need to escape out strings in case they contain special characters.

Comment: I don't need to write file to XML. I need to write text file with the help of XML file which act as template. XML file contains information regarding field name and field value to be displayed.

Comment: @AkhilKhandelwal Ok, but you can use the strategy of processing one record at a time and stream hat data to wherever it is going.

Comment: Thanks peter, I am doing just the same but wanted a design pattern to make sure strategy is right and change if not.